# Definition of a $n$ - form on a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, manifolds, differential-topology, definition

I am confused about the definition of a differential form on a manifold.

The definition I have comes from Bott and Tu and is as follows:

A differential form, $\omega$, on a manifold $M$ is a collection of forms $\omega_U$ for $U$ in the atlas defining $M$, which are compatible in the following sense:

$i^*\omega_U=j^*\omega_V$ where $i,j$ are the inclusion maps.

I am confused as to what exactly $\omega_u$ is. Is it the pull back by a chart of a form on Euclidean space?

**Moreover, how can I fail the compatibility criterion? It seems to me like it should always be true.**

I think I simple example would really help me understand but I can't find one.

Thanks for your help,

Comment: see if you can construct everything for the unit sphere in $\mathbb R^3.$ everything can be written using the ambient $x,y,z$ coordinates

Comment: You may just think of an $n$ form on $M$ as a collection of $\omega_U$ ($n$-form on open coordinate $U$) such that $f^*\omega_V = \omega_U$, where $f :U' \to V'$ is the change of coordinate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A differential form $\omega$ of degree $k$  on a real manifold $M$ of dimension $n$ is, formally, a section of the $p$-th exterior power of the cotangent bundle $T^{*}M$ over $M$, in symbols:

$$\omega\in \Gamma(\wedge^k T^{*}M).$$

This means that $\omega$ is a smooth map  $M\rightarrow \wedge^k T^{*}M$ which, at any point $p\in M$ is given by

$$\omega_U(p):=\omega_{U,i_1,\dots,i_k}(p)dx^{i_1}\wedge\dots\wedge dx^{i_k}, $$

where $(x^{1},\dots, x^{n})$ denote local coordinates in the open set $U$ centered at $p\in M$. In other words, the differential form $\omega$ can be seen as a collection of "local" forms like above; any coordinate transformation $f: U\rightarrow V$ induces a transformation $\omega_V=f^{*}\circ\omega_U$ as pointed out by @John. 
As often happens in differential geometry, one starts with local data and gives a rule to glue them into a global structure (when possible).

$f^{*}\omega$ is the pull-back of $\omega$ along $f$: you can find its definition on every textbook. Essentially, the coordinate transformation formula reduces to an identity involving the Jacobian matrix of $f$.

Comment: I am still a bit confused. Why is the existence of an n-form different to that of an k-form? My current understanding of a differential form is a smooth function, tensor a product of 'dx', where the 'dx' are formal symbols. So if I have a (k-1)-form, why can I not turn this into a k-form by adding another dx to the product?

Comment: If $n$ is the real dimension of your manifold $M$, then differential forms can be of degree $0,1,...,n$. If you choose any $k\in \{0,...,n\}$ you can apply the considerations above. The proper way to turn a $k-1$ form into a $k$ form is expressed by a specific operation called exterior differentiation.

Comment: I think I am asking a silly question but, if $f(X)dx_1...dx_{k-1}$ is a (k-1)-form then is $f(X)dx_1...dx_{k-1}d_k$ a k-form?

Comment: yes, it is true: $k$ is the length of the string $dx_1\wedge...\wedge dx_k$ in the local coordinates expression of the diff. form $\omega$. In my answer the diff. form is of degree $k$.

Comment: In that case, doesn't the existence of a nowhere vanishing function (0-form) imply the existence of a nowhere vanishing k-form for all k<n+1? I can just multiply by the desired number if dx's.

Comment: this is a nice remark! Why don't you write it as a question? it has an interesting answer. Btw, feel free to flag the answer above if you found it useful.

Comment: @Avitus You should have pointed out that the definition in question is plain non sense. I found this kind of sloppy work by Bott and Tu so frustrating when I read this book. This is no way to define it. If the form is already defined on U and V by restriction from a well defined form on the manifold, surely the statement is true via restrictions to intersection. But, it has be defined in the first place and the authors do not define it of course as you correctly do.

Answer (score 1):

This is just an intuitive opinion. I believe this works the same way as the differentiable structure definition works for a manifold. We want a maximal atlas that is the collection of all compatible atlases given any representative atlas. This probably tries to do something similar for a form. In as many words, as Avitus notes, this is an attempt to relate the local and global existences.